# Openni+Kinect+Other Machines

Tags: ros, kinect, openni, openni-launch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to get data from a Kinect connected to a machine and pass it to my laptop (which is connected to the first machine). I know I can run roscore on the first machine and make it the master. Then, I was wondering if I can run openni_launch on my laptop and make it recognize that a kinect is connected to the master machine (not my laptop). So far roslaunch on openni fails on my laptop because the kinect is not connected directly to my laptop.

Any help is appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67107/openni+kinect+other-machines/) by [Qandeel](https://answers.ros.org/users/5107/qandeel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-07-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To my knowledge, this is not possible with just OpenNI (which was not developed for this usecase).

You might look into the possibility to install something on both machines which allows you to forward the USB-data from the BeagleBone to a virtual USB-port on the laptop - I don't know if there are solutions for this. Afaik some router manufacturers allow for this in order to access printers attached to the router from any connected PC as if it were connected locally.

Even if it is possible, you'd probably have to use a GBit-network connection as a Kinect uses about 60% of the available USB-bandwidth (which should be around 480 MBit/s, so 250+ used by the Kinect).

---

Originally posted by [Philip](https://answers.ros.org/users/4292/philip/) with karma: 990 on 2013-07-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It doesn't matter which machine has the master attached as long as both machines have full connectivity and agree on the master. Check [this page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines) and [this page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/NetworkSetup) for how to do that.

openni_launch contains the driver for the kinect, so you'll have to launch that on the machine with the kinect.

However, you can use roslaunch to remotely launch the openni driver on the other machine from your laptop.  Then, through ROS mechanisms, you could use the data in nodes running on your laptop as if the kinect were hooked up to your laptop. Check out [the machine tag](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/XML/machine), [tips for large projects](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/Roslaunch%20tips%20for%20larger%20projects#roslaunch.2BAC8-Tutorials.2BAC8-Roslaunch_tips_for_larger_projects.Machine_tags_and_Environment_Variables), and the [roslaunch architecture](http://ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/Architecture) for how to do that.

---

Originally posted by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) with karma: 3562 on 2013-07-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Qandeel](https://answers.ros.org/users/5107/qandeel/) on 2013-07-11**:
I don't have openni drivers installed on the other machine. It's a BeagleBone with an ARM processor and I have yet to figure out how I can install the ros openni on it. I wanted to know if openni can run on my laptop but look for the Kinect off of the BeagleBone rather than itself.

**Comment by [agonzamart](https://answers.ros.org/users/3277/agonzamart/) on 2013-07-11**:
As fas as I know, you have to run openni on the machine you plug the kinect in. The driver must run inside the machine connected directly to the kinect so you have to install the openni there.